# Miscounting switch conditions with enum in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a enum with 3 values `(A, B, C)`.

A switch expression is used in a `foo` method to do some stuff according to the enum value.

I also have a test case with different values as parameter to insure all conditions are covered.

However, The results on SonarQube shows **"partially covered by tests (3 of 4 conditions)."**
[image]

My questions:

1. Why are there 4 conditions? I think it should be 3 conditions.`(A, B, C)`
2. What should I do to fully cover 4 conditions?

```
public enum FooType
{
    A, B, C
}

public class TestCondition
{
    public int foo (FooType type)
    {
        int ans = 0;

        switch (type) {
            case A:
                ans = 10;
                break;
            case B:
                ans = 20;
                break;
            case C:
                ans = 30;
                break;
        }

        return ans;
    }
}

@Test
public void testFoo ()
{
    TestCondition testCondition = new TestCondition();

    testCondition.foo(FooType.A);
    testCondition.foo(FooType.B);
    testCondition.foo(FooType.C);
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

Try adding default case and the result is the same.

It seems the fourth condition is the `default` case.

1. What should I do to cover `default` case?
2. Why did SonarQube count in `default` since I didn't add `default` in my switch statement?

[image]

Comment: try adding a default case and see if sonarQube will handle it correctly. I think there's an implicit default, when you don't specify any.

Comment: @Mustafa I add default case. Please see the [update] above. Who add the implicit default case? Java compiler, SonarQube, or JaCoCo? Do you have any reference about the implicit default case? Thank you.

Comment: `default` (implicit or explicit) is a valid branch, in case other 3 branches missed, so 4 branches is correct no matter what you are switching (even it is `enum`). This should be redundant warning and ignored as you cannot do anything except adding another value to your test. For example, add an `UNKNOWN` enum and `testCondition.foo(FooType.UNKNOWN);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are there 4 conditions? I think it should be 3 conditions.(A, B, C)

No, there are **4** branches: A, B, C, and the other value which is not A, B, C. Yes, I don't care your enum has only 3 constants, that thing I care is that your switch statement has 4 valid branches to go, no matter you define `default` or not.

> What should I do to fully cover 4 conditions?

Ignore the warning, it should be redundant. If you want fully coverage, you have to add 1 more case to your test. Since you are switching an enum, you have to add another constant to your enum, too. Like: `DEFAULT`, `UNKNOWN`, etc.

Comment: Adding another constant (e.g., `DEFAULT`, `UNKNOWN`) may be troublesome. The constant would be redundant since it's only purpose is pass the condition coverages. Do you have any better way to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: @cwliang Sadly, no. If you take a look into the bytecode, your switch always has 4 branches. There's no way to fully cover all the branches if you don't pass the valid value for it. Or you just need to ignore it.